# The Beatles' song "Yellow Submarine" sounds slightly off-tune on YouTube

Tags: recording, performance

Hope it is not extremely off-topic for I have no idea where to ask else...

Listening to [Yellow Submarine](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krIus0i9xn8) song my wife pointed that it sounds off-tune. I never thought of this (my ears are not as well trained), but listening now attentively, I found that it really is so, but not during the chorus. The chorus sounds perfect (?)

So the questions are:

- is it really slightly off-tune (not just impression or problem of digitizing old record);
- if yes, then is there any (semi-)official comment on this (simply scenic effect?) - I browsed wiki article but nothing of the kind is mentioned.

Comment: Aw come on. It's Ringo singing...

Comment: The link you have provided is of a cover band doing their own version of the Beatles song. If this cover band is out of tune or not, I do not much care.

Answer (score 4):

(as pointed out in the comments, thanks @Wheat @Tim)

This video does not actually appear to be the Beatles, although it is billed as though it were.  As far as I can tell, there's no version with the legitimate original song on YouTube, probably because of copyright issues.

Even in the original version, however, the lead singer is Ringo Starr, the drummer of the band, who famously asked "what would you do if I sang out of tune?" on "A Little Help From My Friends."  He didn't typically sing lead except on the band's more lighthearted novelty numbers.